# Получить конкретный элемент из JSON

Tags: android, json, gson

Есть такой JSON файл, можно ли по id как-то получить конкретный элемент из этого файла?

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "title": "Заголовок 1",
      "author": "Автор 1",
      "source": "(null)",
      "text": "Текст 1",
      "favorite": "0",
      "filename": "file_1",
      "image": "file_1",
      "category": "Категория"
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "title": "Заголовок 2",
      "author": "Автор 2",
      "source": "(null)",
      "text": "Текст 2",
      "favorite": "0",
      "filename": "file_2",
      "image": "file_2",
      "category": "Категория"
    },
    {
      "id": "3",
      "title": "Заголовок 3",
      "author": "Автор 3",
      "source": "(null)",
      "text": "Текст 3",
      "favorite": "0",
      "filename": "file_3",
      "image": "file_3",
      "category": "Категория"
    }
  ]
}
```

Есть класс, описывающий элемент

Item

```
public class Item implements {

    @SerializedName("id")
    @Expose
    private int id;
    @SerializedName("title")
    @Expose
    private String title;
    @SerializedName("author")
    @Expose
    private String author;
    @SerializedName("source")
    @Expose
    private String source;
    @SerializedName("text")
    @Expose
    private String text;
    @SerializedName("favorite")
    @Expose
    private String favorite;
    @SerializedName("filename")
    @Expose
    private String filename;
    @SerializedName("image")
    @Expose
    private String image;
    @SerializedName("category")
    @Expose
    private String category;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getAuthor() {
        return author;
    }

    public void setAuthor(String author) {
        this.author = author;
    }

    public String getSource() {
        return source;
    }

    public void setSource(String source) {
        this.source = source;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public String getFavorite() {
        return favorite;
    }

    public void setFavorite(String favorite) {
        this.favorite = favorite;
    }

    public String getFilename() {
        return filename;
    }

    public void setFilename(String filename) {
        this.filename = filename;
    }

    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(String image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    public String getCategory() {
        return category;
    }

    public void setCategory(String category) {
        this.category = category;
    }

}
```

ItemList

```
public class ItemList {

    @SerializedName("items")
    @Expose
    private List<Item> items = null;

    public List<Item> getItems() {
        return items;
    }

    public void setItems(List<Item> items) {
        this.items = items;
    }

}
```

Все объекты получаю так:

```
private void loadData() {
    try {
        InputStream json = getAssets().open("items.json");
        itemList = new Gson().fromJson(new InputStreamReader(json, "UTF-8"), ItemList.class);
        myAdapter = new MyAdapter(itemList.getItems(), MainActivity.this);
        rvList.setAdapter(MyAdapter);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Можно, но в любом случае вам необходимо распарсить весь файл (строку) (или как минимум до нужного элемента - не помню, у json есть потоковые парсеры) и потом только его вытаскивать его из списка: itemList.getItems().getId(id). Есть ещё один вариант искать в файле по ключу и дальше регулярками доставать, но вам это ни к чему и так вы только проиграете.

Comment: Поняла, спасибо. Мне вот нужно было знать есть ли какой-то иной способ не выбирая все в список получить сразу нужный элемент.